# Git Clone then git pull

Tags: git, github

Hi there I just did a `git clone` of a repo on my PROD server, then changed folder name sudo mv folder correct_folder_name

I have made changes on local machine then `git push` to repo.

I go back to my PROD server and git pull, but there is not .git repo `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

What are the steps to pull next commit? 
`git init`
`git merge`

not sure ?

Comment: If your server has a bare repo and you pushed to it, there’s no need to pull on its side. It already has the changes. (There might be another problem, though, because I thought it gave you a more specific error if you tried `pull` in a bare repo…?)

Comment: Hi there, i need to pull to get latest changes as I am working on my localhost site, not pushing from PROD site. Everytime I make a change on localhost --> repo I want to pull latest changes on PROD, but it is not working

Comment: I think when I moved folder name after I cloned I lost the connection to repo

Comment: Please check "git remote" in the server cloned directory.

Comment: Which folder did you rename? The main git folder where the `.git` folder is in? Did you clone the repo on your PROD server as well? It seems that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is terribly old, bu maybe someone will You shouldn't rename a repo outside the git. You should use:

```
git mv olddir newdir
```

It consists of the following commands:

```
mv olddir newdir
git add newdir
git remove olddir
```

So I guess that running the two remaining git commands would help to first correct the problem with the repo. Then you should be able to do the pull.